# Any idea how these lat/lon pairs are formatted?

Tags: xml, formatting, schema, gis, gpx

I got this snippet which is part of GPX data, can't figure what format the lat/lon pairs are though...

```
 <rte><number>0</number><name>0</name><cmt>2.10000000000e+001</cmt>
 <rtept lat="151234.04567902" lon="982651.91230503"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151172.75643152" lon="982728.52370036"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151172.75643152" lon="982835.49986435"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151195.41944394" lon="982998.67473486"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151217.32983318" lon="983156.42868444"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151163.84175119" lon="983446.15612336"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151128.18302986" lon="983713.59653336"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151119.26834951" lon="983945.37855011"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151118.97110602" lon="983947.85426694"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151092.52430852" lon="984168.24555844"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="151059.42758994" lon="984332.72915336"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="150115.61320460" lon="984460.79845102"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="149996.49861343" lon="984385.56795844"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="149883.65336668" lon="984410.64500803"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="149902.46074377" lon="984592.45140295"></rtept>
 <rtept lat="149653.23683277" lon="984630.62947619"></rtept>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Thx for all the comments. You headed me in the right direction. shp2text is actually assuming data to be in WGS84 projection. Mine was 'Lambert Conformal Conic'. So, I used a GIS tool called MapWindow to re-project the shapefile to WGS84. Then I used GPS Trackmaker to import the shapefile. The corresponding KML file looks just fine. Thx everybody...

Comment: State Plane projection uses a mix of Lamber Conformal Conic and transverse Mercator, so my answer is essentially correct ;), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like State Plane New York projection (East?). I tried importing your xy data in ArcGIS with that projection (NAD83 State Plane NY East, meters), then setting the dataframe projection to WGS84 lat/long, which returns lat/long values similar to what you would expect for NY...

EDIT: [State Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Plane_Coordinate_System) uses a mix of transverse Mercator and Lambert Conformal Conic projections, so you should also try these.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this data is invalid. This looks like [GPX data](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_wptType) and the values for `lat` / `lon` need to be within -90.0 and +90.0 (-180.0 / +180.0).

shp2text doesn't do any validation on the shape file data, it simply exports the shape vertex coordinates as GPX data. So the lat / lon numbers you are seeing are the coordinates of your original shape file. Are you converting geographical data?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I created the GPX data converting a shapefile with shp2text. Wonder what could went wrong...

Comment: Yep, the shapefile I'm trying to convert should include school districts of NY elementary schools. So, basically polygons.

Comment: Yes, but in what coordinate system?

Comment: It might be some weird projection!

Answer (score 0):

I did some calculations... Is it possible that the very first coordinates indicate a position somewhere near chicago?

In my calculation any coordinate is provided in seconds. So I divided the value / 3600 to get h and so on ...

I get the following values for the first coordinates

```
lat: 42,00945713
lng: 272,9588645
```

if you need my excel sheet - send me an mail to franz.pilgerstorfer@gmx.at and I'll respond.

hth

Comment: It should be NY. The shapefile provides school districts of New York City. Interesting hint though...